# tsc error TS1110 node.d.ts Node.js v6.x

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsc

When running `tsc` I get a lot of errors of the form

`typings/node/node.d.ts(Ln,Col): error TS1110: Type expected.`

FYI: The first line of `node.d.ts` says

> // Type definitions for Node.js v6.x

What is the cause for these errors and how to resolve them?

Steps to reproduce:
In a directory having only file `tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "outDir": "."
    }
}
```

next, execute the command `tsd install body-parser --save`, output:

```
- body-parser                  / body-parser
  -> express                   > express
  -> serve-static              > serve-static
  -> express-serve-static-core > express-serve-static-core
  -> node                      > node
  -> mime                      > mime

> running install..

> written 6 files:

   - body-parser/body-parser.d.ts
   - express-serve-static-core/express-serve-static-core.d.ts
   - express/express.d.ts
   - mime/mime.d.ts
   - node/node.d.ts
   - serve-static/serve-static.d.ts
```

The directory now has subdirectory`/typings`.

Next command:

```
$ tsc
typings/node/node.d.ts(87,23): error TS1110: Type expected.
typings/node/node.d.ts(244,57): error TS1110: Type expected.
typings/node/node.d.ts(245,48): error TS1110: Type expected.
typings/node/node.d.ts(246,50): error TS1110: Type expected.
typings/node/node.d.ts(247,60): error TS1110: Type expected.
typings/node/node.d.ts(248,45): error TS1110: Type expected.
typings/node/node.d.ts(249,37): error TS1110: Type expected.
typings/node/node.d.ts(291,57): error TS1110: Type expected.
typings/node/node.d.ts(292,48): error TS1110: Type expected.
typings/node/node.d.ts(293,50): error TS1110: Type expected.
typings/node/node.d.ts(294,60): error TS1110: Type expected.
typings/node/node.d.ts(295,45): error TS1110: Type expected.
typings/node/node.d.ts(496,54): error TS1110: Type expected.
typings/node/node.d.ts(540,57): error TS1110: Type expected.
typings/node/node.d.ts(541,48): error TS1110: Type expected.
typings/node/node.d.ts(542,50): error TS1110: Type expected.
typings/node/node.d.ts(543,61): error TS1110: Type expected.
typings/node/node.d.ts(544,65): error TS1110: Type expected.
typings/node/node.d.ts(545,60): error TS1110: Type expected.
typings/node/node.d.ts(546,45): error TS1110: Type expected.
typings/node/node.d.ts(547,37): error TS1110: Type expected.
typings/node/node.d.ts(869,35): error TS1110: Type expected.
typings/node/node.d.ts(1950,52): error TS1005: '=' expected.
typings/node/node.d.ts(1951,76): error TS1005: '=' expected.
typings/node/node.d.ts(1952,52): error TS1005: '=' expected.
typings/node/node.d.ts(1952,96): error TS1005: '=' expected.
typings/node/node.d.ts(1962,54): error TS1005: '=' expected.
typings/node/node.d.ts(1963,74): error TS1005: '=' expected.
typings/node/node.d.ts(1964,54): error TS1005: '=' expected.
typings/node/node.d.ts(1964,94): error TS1005: '=' expected.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TLDR;**

```
npm install -g typescript
```

and not

```
npm install -g tsc
```

**Explanation:**

I noticed that Visual Studio 2015 has no issues compiling the same directory of TypeScript files so I examined the Build log (with Diagnostic verbosity under Options) and found this line:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.8\tsc.exe  --module CommonJS --sourcemap --target ES5 --noEmitOnError --locale en-US
```

I had been using the tsc compiler installed by `npm install tsc --global` but its version is 1.5.3 as of today, whereas the one noted above is version 1.8.9.